# how to updates and inserts arrays at the same time in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

the doc is :

```
 {
  "_id" : 1,
  "class":{
       "grades1":[
          { "grade" : 80, "std" : 6 },
          { "grade" : 82, "std" : 4 },
          { "grade" : 85, "std" : 6 }
       ]
   }
 }
```

my update statement is :

```
db.user_data.update({"_id":1},{$inc:{"class.grades1.$[index1].std":1},$addToSet:{"class.grades2.$[index2]":{"grade":90, "std":8}}},{arrayFilters:[{"index1":{$exists:true},"index1.grade":82},{"index2":{$exists:false}}]})
```

I want the result:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "class":{
       "grades1":[
          { "grade" : 80, "std" : 6 },
          { "grade" : 82, "std" : 5 },
          { "grade" : 85, "std" : 6 }
       ],
       "grades2":[
          { "grade" : 90, "std" : 8 }
       ]
   }
 }
```

But there was an error, please help me, thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you like to achieve, simply try `db.user_data.updateOne({ _id: 1 }, { $set: { "class.grades2": [{ "grade": 90, "std": 8 }] } })`

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Find the 'grade' field. If it already exists, update the 'std' value. If it does not exist, insert a new object